# How can I align my div's under my header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

How can I make my documents and my video align under my bootstrap header jumbotron horizontally? I just want the content to be in line with the header directly under it.

CSS

```
.container2 {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap; /* Align on the same line */
      justify-content: space-between; /* Equal margin between the child elements */
      }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container2">
         <div class="left">
            <p  style=" margin: 12px auto 6px auto; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; -x-system-font: none; display: block;"></p>
            <iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="https://www.scribd.com/embeds/344420651/content?start_page=1&view_mode=scroll&access_key=key-8enfvS2L2K0nh24zmVG8&show_recommendations=true" data-auto-height="false" data-aspect-ratio="0.7729220222793488" scrolling="no" id="doc_97914" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
         </div>
         <div class="center">
            <p  style=" margin: 12px auto 6px auto; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; -x-system-font: none; display: block;"></p>
            <iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="https://www.scribd.com/embeds/344420651/content?start_page=1&view_mode=scroll&access_key=key-8enfvS2L2K0nh24zmVG8&show_recommendations=true" data-auto-height="false" data-aspect-ratio="0.7729220222793488" scrolling="no" id="doc_97914" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6O7VlTCPYVU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Full Site code - https://jsfiddle.net/1mx7ygr1/

I'm aware that I'm using bootstrap and using other ways of coding the page and the webpage is not fully responsive. However, trying to get the basics on point and get a basic understand than develop my skills as I've only recently started.

Comment: Is the video and documents not aligned on the same line in your snippet or am I missing something?. Aren't they under your navbar header?

Comment: Updated post, I'm looking for the documents and video to be aligned with the header.

Comment: Vertical, or horizontally? Directly under each other? Off to the right? You're still being a little vague.

Comment: I have put the content horizontally now I just want the content to be in line with the header.

Comment: you mean the video is a little higher than the documents? and you want it to vertical align from the top. Align at the same height level?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unecessary paragraph tag in the `.left` and `.center` div. These paragraphs are empty. Also they are adding space.

Change them to `display:none` or remove (if you'd like)

```
.left p,.center p{
  display:none !important;
}
```

[fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/5zwow1y0/)

Comment: Please re-read my answer....I stated if neccessary remove the element . I cannot say if the p tags are there to place something inside at a later time.

Comment: The p tags are blocks elements whether or not they are empty they will add space....this is what is causing the document div to shift downwards..selfish is what you see something working and still votes it down

Comment: havent you seen a snippet in my answer